# While uploading an image with php, deleting the old image at the same time. (unlink)

Tags: php

first of all I'm sorry for using Google translate. I don't know much about these things. As a result of my Google research, I learned that I could delete the old image with unlink, but it didn't work.
The code below loads an image into the database and file but does not delete the old image.

```
if ($_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name'] != "")
{
    $boyutdort = $_FILES['fotodort']['sizedort'];
    $tip = mime_content_type($_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name']);
    if($tip!="image/jpeg" && $tip!="image/jpg" && $tip!="image/png" && $tip!="application/pdf"){
        echo 'Dosya Jpeg veya Png yada Gif , PDF formatında olmalı';
    }elseif ($boyutdort > (1024 * 1024 * 30)) {
        echo 'Dosya 10MB den büyük olamaz.';
    } else {
        $tipdort = $_FILES['fotodort']['type'];
        $isimdort = $_FILES['fotodort']['name'];
        $uzantidort = explode('.', $isimdort);
        $uzantidort = $uzantidort[count($uzantidort) - 1];
        $randomdort = rand();
        $dosyadort = $_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name'];
        $foto_urldort = $randomdort . "." . $uzantidort;
        copy($dosyadort, '../assets/images/admin-img/' . $foto_urldort);
        if (file_exists("../assets/images/admin-img/".$foto_urldort)) {
            unlink("../assets/images/admin-img/".$foto_urldort);
        }
        $settings = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE general_settings SET foto_dark = '".$foto_urldort."' WHERE id=1 ");
        $settings->execute();
    }
}
```

I tried to integrate the code I found from a different system into this code, but I could not succeed.

```
       if (file_exists("../assets/images/admin-img/".$fotodort)) {
            unlink("../assets/images/admin-img/".$fotodort);
        }
```

I would be grateful if you could help with this. There are more than 20 image upload fields. I will update all of them with the method I will learn from you.
It will also work if you teach a different code structure that will do the same operations.

Comment: can you check if the file exist in the directory, if so try to echo something in the if statement to check if it works, and then try to unlink the file without if statement

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question as I can't add code as a comment. Also thank you for the answer and for the edit suggestion.
Newly uploaded file is in directory

Comment: cevapıma baksana olmazsa duzeltim

Comment: hemen deniyorum

Comment: resim klasöre yükleniyor. veritabanına dosya ismi yüklenmiyor ve eski resmi silmiyor :(

Comment: ok then lets solve it in the chat

Comment: oh we can't till you have <20 reputation

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and the system works fine.
Do you check if block sequences are in the right place?

```
if ($_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name'] != "") {
      $boyutdort = $_FILES['fotodort']['sizedort'];
      $tip = mime_content_type($_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name']);
      if($tip!="image/jpeg" && $tip!="image/jpg" && $tip!="image/png" && $tip!="application/pdf"){
        echo 'Dosya Jpeg veya Png yada Gif , PDF formatında olmalı';
      }elseif ($boyutdort > (1024 * 1024 * 30)) {
       echo 'Dosya 10MB den büyük olamaz.';
     } else {
      $tipdort = $_FILES['fotodort']['type'];
      $isimdort = $_FILES['fotodort']['name'];
      $uzantidort = explode('.', $isimdort);
      $uzantidort = $uzantidort[count($uzantidort) - 1];
      $randomdort = rand();
      $dosyadort = $_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name'];
      $foto_urldort = $randomdort . "." . $uzantidort;
      copy($dosyadort, '../assets/images/admin-img/' . $foto_urldort);
      echo " 
      <script>
      const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 6000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: (toast) => {
          toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
          toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
        }
        })

        Toast.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Başarı ile güncellendi.'
          })
          </script> ";
          $settings = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE general_settings SET foto_dark = '".$foto_urldort."' WHERE id=1 ");
          $settings->execute();
          
            if (file_exists('../assets/images/admin-img/'.$_POST['eskiresimsil']) && $dosyadort) {
                unlink('../assets/images/admin-img/'.$_POST['eskiresimsil']);
            }
        
         }
 }
```

I wrote the old image name before the submit button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="eskiresimsil" value="<?=$ayar['foto_dark'];?>">
```

Comment: excellent, I couldn't fin it for you anyway nice to meet you

Comment: Çok teşekkür ederim. harikasın.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    $size = $_FILES['fotodort']['sizedort'];
    $type = mime_content_type($_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name']);
    if($type!="image/jpeg" && $type!="image/jpg" && $type!="image/png" && $type!="application/pdf"){
        echo 'Dosya JPEG/JPG, PNG, yada PDF formatında olmalı';
    }elseif ($boyutdort > (1024 * 1024 * 30)) {
        echo 'Dosya 10MB den büyük olamaz.';
    } else {
        $dosyadort = $_FILES['fotodort']['tmp_name'];
        $name = rand().$_FILES['fotodort']['extension'];
        copy($dosyadort, '../assets/images/admin-img/' . $name);

        $upload = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE general_settings SET foto_dark ='".$foto_urldort."' WHERE id=1");
        $upload->execute();

         if (file_exists("../assets/images/admin-img/".$fotodort) && $dosyadort) {
            unlink("../assets/images/admin-img/".$fotodort);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried. didn't work

Comment: don't worry I write this before you solve it, 1hr ago

Comment: I thought it was a new answer, sorry Can you check if the structure and sequence of the code I wrote as a solution is correct?

Comment: while the older one is slow you can just add `&& $dosyadort` to the if statement so it'll be like the new edit

Comment: no no check the edit and you'll get it

Comment: if (file_exists('../assets/images/admin-img/'.$_POST['eskiresimsil']) && $dosyadort) {
 unlink('../assets/images/admin-img/'.$_POST['eskiresimsil']);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241352/discussion-between-data-marketing-and-sarout).